# Mercurial keywords extension to expand on every commit

Tags: mercurial, commit, keyword

I need to use the hg keyword extension to embed the build date and revision into a source file. Leaving aside the whole "you really don't want to be doing that" argument, how can I do this?

Here's what my source file (`lib/foo/version.rb`) looks like (which happens to be Ruby, but that's only relevant from the point of view that I don't have a "compile" step in my build which I could do a -DREVISION="$(hg id)" in):

```
module Foo
  VERSION = {
    :date => "$Date$",
    :changeset => "$Revision$"
  }
end
```

The problem is that $Revision$ and $Date$ are expanded with the changeset and commit date *of that file*, whereas what I need is the tip changeset and commit date of the whole repository.

I don't see an obvious template I can use in `hg help templates`, nor does the keyword extension mention anything with global scope. Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: I understand you want to leave aside the "you don't want to do it" part, but for anyone else reading this: The keyword extension page does a great job of explaining why this is probably a bad idea.  In short: with a DVCS all files in the checkout are from the same revision so just checking the output of `hg parents` or the contents of `.hg_archive.txt` is almost always a better plan.  Having all your files modified all the time screws with `hg status` and DVCS usage in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install a `post-commit` hook that updates the file:

```
[hooks]
post-commit = sed -i lib/foo/version.rb \
  -e "s|\$Date.*\$|\$Date: $(date)\$|" \
  -e "s|\$Version.*\$|\$Version: $(hg id -i)\$|"
```

You should then probably add the version file to the `.hgignore` file -- it will change after every commit and thus always be dirty. You could also add a encode filter that will clean up the version file:

```
[encode]
lib/foo/version.rb =  sed -e "s|\$Date.*\$|\$Date\$|" \
                          -e "s|\$Version.*\$|\$Version\$|"
```

This script will make Mercurial see the file as clean -- no matter what date and changeset has it really contains, Mercurial will see it as containing un-expanded `$Date$` and `$Version$` keywords:

```
$ hg commit -m test
$ hg tip
changeset:   7:df81c9ddc9ad
tag:         tip
user:        Martin Geisler 
date:        Wed Apr 06 14:39:26 2011 +0200
summary:     test

$ hg status
$ hg cat version.py
date = "$Date$"
version = "$Version$"
$ cat version.py
date = "$Date: Wed Apr  6 14:39:26 CEST 2011$"
version = "$Version: df81c9ddc9ad$"
```

Comment: Ok, I'll give that a try. It looks like a much simpler version of what the keywords extension is doing under the hood, just on a per-repository rather than per-file basis.

Comment: Great solution, but is there a way to achieve this on a Windows box as well, without having to install additional libs?

Comment: @Jon: there's no built-in way but you could write a small Python extension for Mercurial to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running your code from a checkout you can invoke hg directly and cache the value.  Something like:

```
module Foo
  VERSION = {
    :version => system("hg log --template '{note|short}-{latesttag}-{latesttagdistance}' -r .")
  }
end
```

and if you're not running the code from inside a checkout on a system with Mercurial installed, then your deploy script can easily get/use the value -- perhaps by using `hg archive` to get the tarball to send which then automatically includes a `.hg_archive.txt`.

I guarantee you there's a prettier way to do this than the keywords extension no matter what your setup is.

Comment: Yeah, that's not going to work for me. I don't even know that I'll have lib/foo/version.rb as a distinct file when deployment happens (which I'm not in control of), let alone that I'll be running from within a repository. I think post-commit might be the only way to get what I'm after.